# Call Functions in DLL using Java

Tags: java, c#, c++, javafx, java-native-interface

I have been looking at ways to call DLL functions in Java. I have successfully done a few tutorials. All the tutorials and examples I have seen have been very basic. Basically, calling a DLL with one function. The DLL I need to load has two public interfaces (`ClassBatchCat` and `ClassItemRecord`). See object browser below.

[image]

I need to access the functions associated with `ClassBatchCat`. See Image below.
[image]

So, how do I access the functions under `ClassBatchCatClass` and how do I access the return code ENUMs. 
This is not a JavaFX question.

Comment: Not an answer, but [this resource](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jni/index.html) may help.

Comment: Thanks @Slaw. I will look at it after lunch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jni4net, which act as bridge between .NET and Java.

Please refer the documentation [here](http://jni4net.com/)

Comment: I think it's an unmanaged DLL. It has Interop in front of the DLL's name in the object browers.

Comment: When I try to load the DLL using jni4net, I get error: `Exception in thread "main" System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\path1\path2\BatchCat2009-21.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.`